# Error on print_usage and fzero while Running Matlab Script in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to run inputfile_calrel_example1 FERUM Matlab scripts from https://www.sigma-clermont.fr/en/ferum in Octave-5.1.0.0 but run into errors with respect to print_usage and fzero as follows:

```
error: Invalid call to fzero.  Correct usage is:

 -- fzero (FUN, X0)
 -- fzero (FUN, X0, OPTIONS)
 -- [X, FVAL, INFO, OUTPUT] = fzero (...)
error: called from
    print_usage at line 91 column 5
    fzero at line 133 column 5
    drho0_dthetaf_integral at line 75 column 22
    mod_corr_solve at line 99 column 54
    form at line 90 column 58
    ferum at line 129 column 33
>>
```

Looking through print_usage.m file reveals line 91 as follows:

```
   error ("Octave:invalid-fun-call", msg);
```

while lines 78 to 92:

```
    if (at_toplev)
    error ("Octave:invalid-fun-call",
           "Invalid call to %s.  Correct usage is:\n\n%s\n%s",
           name, usage_string, __additional_help_message__ ());
  else
    msg = sprintf ("Invalid call to %s.  Correct usage is:\n\n%s",
                   name, usage_string);
    ## Ensure that the error doesn't end up with a newline, as that disables
    ## backtraces.
    if (msg(end) == "\n")
      msg(end) = " ";
    endif

    error ("Octave:invalid-fun-call", msg);
  endif
```

and fzero lines 132 to 134 are as follows:

```
  if (nargin < 2 | nargin > 3)
    print_usage (mfilename ());
  end
```

I would like to have hints as to how to resolve the above error messages.

Best regards
Aliyu Aziz

Comment: how did you / the script call `fzero`

Comment: ``` drho0_dthetafi.mu    = fzero('betadrho0_dthetaf',0,optimset('fzero'),dF_dthetafi.mu,PHI2,F,dPHI2_dZi,dZi_dthetafi.mu,dPHI2_drho0,detJ,WIP);
```

Comment: fzero was called by drho0_dthetaf_integral at line 75 column 22 as shown above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `fzero` was called with the following arguments.

```
drho0_dthetafi.mu = fzero( ...
    'betadrho0_dthetaf'    ...
    , 0                    ...
    , optimset('fzero')    ...
    , dF_dthetafi.mu       ...
    , PHI2                 ...
    , F                    ...
    , dPHI2_dZi            ...
    , dZi_dthetafi.mu      ...
    , dPHI2_drho0          ...
    , detJ                 ...
    , WIP                  ...
);
```

From the documentation (`help fzero`) you can see that the above call is not a valid `fzero` call:

> ```
> -- fzero (FUN, X0, OPTIONS)
>      Find a zero of a univariate function
>
>    FUN is a function handle, inline function, or string containing the
>      name of the function to evaluate.
>
>     X0 should be a two-element vector specifying two points which
>      bracket a zero. If X0 is a single scalar then several nearby and distant
>      values are probed in an attempt to obtain a valid bracketing. If this is not
>      successful, the function fails.
>
>     OPTIONS is a structure specifying additional options.
>      To initialize an options structure with default values for 'fzero'
>      use 'options = optimset ("fzero")'.
> ```

So as you see, the extra arguments after 'optimset' trigger an error.

I'm assuming that the extra arguments were intended to be arguments to the `betadrho0_dthetaf` function. In general the function FUN expects a single argument (since it is univariate). If your `betadrho0_dthetaf` function expects a number of other parameters, then instead of using it in fzero via string, wrap it around an anonymous function handle which *does* only take a single argument, and uses your intended function internally to calculate the intended result, e.g.

```
drho0_dthetafi.mu = fzero(  ...
    @(x) betadrho0_dthetaf( ...
        x                   ...
        , dF_dthetafi.mu    ...
        , PHI2              ...
        , F                 ...
        , dPHI2_dZi         ...
        , dZi_dthetafi.mu   ...
        , dPHI2_drho0       ...
        , detJ              ...
        , WIP               ...
    )                       ...     
    , 0                     ...
    , optimset('fzero')     ...
);
```

or something along those lines, depending on how you would call that beta function.

Comment: Thank you very much Tasos, this helped me cross the hurdle.

Comment: @AliyuA.Aziz my pleasure. Please mark the answer as accepted if it is the solution to your problem. (and if not, feel free to create another answer with the details, for the benefit of future users)!.